# Docker Checkpoint/Restore with CRIU - Kernel doesn't support PTRACE_O_SUSPEND_SECCOMP

Tags: docker, centos7, rhel7, checkpointing

I am attempting to do a hello-world example of docker checkpoint/restore with CRIU (https://criu.org/Docker).

Here is the output from `criu check --all`

```
Error (criu/cr-check.c:648): Kernel doesn't support 
PTRACE_O_SUSPEND_SECCOMP
Error (criu/cr-check.c:692): Dumping seccomp filters not supported: 
Input/output error
Error (criu/cr-check.c:919): cgroupns not supported. This is not fatal.
Looks good but some kernel features are missing
which, depending on your process tree, may cause
dump or restore failure.
```

I am having trouble when I go to actually create the checkpoint, it does not stop the running container, but says it creates the checkpoint. I assume this is because of the above errors reported with --all. Of course thereafter, when I go to restore, it does not actually restore.

I see multiple kernel patches towards the bottom necessary to support CRIU with Docker. Are these patches supported on RHEL7.4? The best discussion i've found about the kernel patches is here: https://trello.com/c/CqLRhFSk/91-follow-up-on-criu-checkpoint-restart-in-userspace-support-and-test-basic-scenarios-snapshot-restore

My current environment:

- RHEL 7.4
- Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
- Running a centos 7.4 docker image as the base

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found the following open issues on Moby:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35691
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35690

Downgrading to docker-ce-17.03 fixed the problem.

Comment: how do I install this version? I get `No package docker-ce-17.03 available.`